# Are there any books in the Lunar Chronicles series that continue the story after Winter?

Tags: lunar-chronicles

I know you have your 4 main books (cinder, scarlet, cress, and winter) and even a few short stories in between some of the (past) books, but are there any more short stories after winter, or full books?

[image]

Comment: Didn’t someone (you?) ask quite a similar question recently?

Comment: Yes, here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145134/what-happens-to-kai-and-cinder-after-winter. The answers to these two questions are very closely related, but the first one is more interesting. I’ll answer your original question when I have some free time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is 'Stars Above'. It is a collection of 8 different short stories that take place all throughout the Lunar Chronicles. However, 2 of the short stories (Glitches, and The Queen's Army) were printed at the back of some copies of Cinder and Scarlet.  There is also one short story (called 'The Little Android') that takes place in The Lunar Chronicles Universe, but only features a small debut of Cinder and that is all of the main characters that we see.

You asked if there are any full books after Winter, and I am proud to proclaim that there are! 'Wires and Nerve' was released January 31st, 2017, and it is a graphic novel featuring Iko. It is also Volume 1, so there are more to come. Volume 2 is estimated for release in 2018. 
There is also a Lunar Chronicles coloring book, that I would highly recommend.